# Get Optimized Image in sitecore

Tags: media-library, performance-optimization

I am using below setting in my application to reduce file size, but no luck. Sometimes it is giving bigger than the original size.

Media.UseLegacyResizing -> value=true
Media.InterpolationMode -> value=Low

What are the settings I need to modify to get file in less size?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore's default setting for `Media.Resizing.Quality` is 95, i.e. 95% quality for JPEG compression. This is the most important setting —I would leave the other ones to their default value. In most cases this will actually increase file size, so I recommend lowering that to a more reasonable value in the 70-85 range (80 being the one I generally go with):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Media.Resizing.Quality" set:value="80" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Note that this only affects images resized with [query parameters](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/media-options-and-query-string-parameters-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms), such as those generated by the Sitecore MVC helper:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("MyImage", item)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying [Dianoga](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga). It is very simple to install and is production ready, and supports multiple different image types (jpg, png, svg).

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, But I am looking for default configuration settings . Can you help me on that.